# Static vue filtered Array is empty when I need it

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a template that needs some non-reactive data in it from my Vuex store. However at the moment, I have to manually switch views to get the data to load. I am assuming I should not use `mounted` or `created`. If I use `watch`, then it basically becomes reactive again, and I only want to get this once.

```js
 data: function () {
    return {
      localreadmode: false,
      myArray: null,
    }
  },

  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      myNodes: (state) => state.myNodes,
      configPositions: (state) => state.configPositions,
      configEmoji: (state) => state.configEmoji,
    }),

    nodes_filtered: function () {
      return this.myNodes.filter((nodes) => {
        return nodes.deleted == false
      })
    },
  },

  // this is to stop sync chasing bug
  myArray: null,
  created() {
    this.$options.myArray = this.nodes_filtered
   console.log(this.nodes_filtered)
// is empty unless I switch views
  },
```

Comment: Don't use variables outside data() function

Comment: Why can't you make data in vuex store reactive? It's the exact way all data in such store should be.

Comment: @anatoly the app is more complicate but I have realtime sync in action and so when you are editing your own text you dont want this on as you cant edit your text - you end up in a race with sync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could still use a watcher that runs only once via the [`vm.$watch`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch) API. It returns a method that can be called to stop watching the value, so your handler could invoke it when `nodes_filtered[]` is not empty.

```js
export default {
  mounted() {
    const unwatch = this.$watch(this.nodes_filtered, value => {
      // ignore falsy values
      if (!value) return

      // stop watching when nodes_filtered[] is not empty
      if (value.length) unwatch()

      // process value here
    })
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/unwatching-state-in-vue-mtzjf?file=/src/components/Demo.vue)

Comment: thanks I did a hack with some timers, but this is not good obviously as would be caught out by hardware / internet speed I suspect... but I will try this instead seems much better

Comment: I had to add  this.$forceUpdate()  into the unwatch but this has reduced some of the complications with timers - thanks